# Work-horse process was terminated unexpectedly RQ and Scrapy

Tags: python, redis, scrapy, splash-screen

I am trying to retrieve a function from redis (rq), which generate a CrawlerProcess but i'm getting

> Work-horse process was terminated unexpectedly (waitpid returned 11)

console log:

> Moving job to 'failed' queue (work-horse terminated unexpectedly;
>   waitpid returned 11)

on the line I marked with comment

> THIS LINE KILL THE PROGRAM

What am I doing wrong?
How I can fix it?

This function I retrieve well from RQ:

```
def custom_executor(url):
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36",
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 20000,  # 100
        'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False,
        'HTTPCACHE_ENABLED': False,
        'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False,

        'SPLASH_URL': 'http://localhost:8050/',
        'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter',
        'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage',

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
            'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
        },

        'SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware': True,
            'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware': True,
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcache.HttpCacheMiddleware': True,
            'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider': True,

            'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
        }
    })

    ### THIS LINE KILL THE PROGRAM
    process.crawl(ExtractorSpider, 
                   start_urls=[url, ], es_client=es_get_connection(),
                   redis_conn=redis_get_connection()) 

    process.start()
```

and this is my ExtractorSpider:

```
class ExtractorSpider(Spider):
    name = "Extractor Spider"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [301, 302, 303]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=process_screenshot,
                            endpoint='execute', args=SPLASH_ARGS)
```

Thank you

Comment: As I learnt with the time and more process failures, it caused due to heavy calculations and not enough memory. After increasing the memory it's work well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process crashed due to heavy calculations while not having enough memory. Increasing the memory fixed that issue.

Comment: How did you increase the memory size? Are there any options for python-rq?

Comment: @Hyunwoo it's depends on the environment you are using. I used pycharm in order to execute the program so increasing Pycharm via `Edit Custom VM Options` did the trick

Comment: I did execute via terminal, so may not the same problem with you. Thanks tho

Comment: My program ran when we used gunicorn but when we introduces rq to track job status, we getting the same error. So clearly, heavy calculations was taken care of prior to rq. Is it that rq reserves some small memroy for itself and does processing only on that whereas in gunicorn everything as CPU limit was available?

More importantly, how to increase this on linux terminal as suggested by both users?

Comment: I went to help->change memory settings in Pycharm, increased to 4000 and this stopped.: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/increasing-memory-heap.html

Comment: Actually it stopped for one run and is back again.

Comment: check how much memory your process needs

Answer (score 1):

For me the process was timing out, had to change the default timeout

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: See the [timeout parameter](https://python-rq.org/docs/jobs/).