# flask_rq, redis, rq Moving job to FailedJobRegistry Work-horse process was terminated unexpectedly (waitpid returned None)

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

Working on flask app, with Flask-RQ2, redis, and rq libraries.  Queue works, but with larger datasets i get the error:

```
Moving job to FailedJobRegistry Work-horse process was terminated unexpectedly (waitpid returned 9)
```

I searched for similar error, and many others suggested pinning redis and rq.  I've tried many combinations and wondering if anyone else has had success with handling this problem?

```
redis==2.10.6
rq==0.12.0
Flask-RQ2==18.2.2
```

Comment: is this helpful [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508289/8006854](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48508289/8006854) ?

Comment: @tobin - i tried that and didn't work in this case